# Grails mapping / sorting associations

Tags: sorting, grails, mapping, associations

in a class I have

```
static hasMany = [allocations: Allocations]
```

.. and a mapping

```
static mapping = {
    allocations sort: 'line'
}
```

I would like to add a second sort field  .. Something like

```
static mapping = {
    allocations sort: ['line', 'qty']
}
```

but I can't get anything to work (tried  allocations sort: ([line:'asc', qty:'asc']) and others ) .. Is it possible to sort associations on more than one property in this way  ?

BTW on grails 2.3.7 ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. `sort()` allows you to sort only by a single property.

> Customizes the default property [ <--singular]  to sort by for query results.

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html

Instead, you can use a criteria query:

```
SomeDomain.withCriteria { 
    allocations {
        order('line')
        order('qty')
    }
}
```